# Pass Object Reference to Intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a gallery app where the user is granted the opportunity to take photos while in an album,can open camera by clicking a button, and the taken photos are automatically added to that album. So, I have an activity called Photos, I use recyclerview in this activity to show the photos in the album. And I have a class called PhotoAdapter and also one activity for camera, namely CamLauncher. CamLauncher is started by an intent created in Photos. When I take a picture and save it, I have to update the dataset the recyclerview uses and that is done by a function in Photos. How can I call the funtion that updates the dataset, which is in Photos.java from CamLauncher.java?

Comment: Add your `Photos.java` and `CamLauncher.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your `CamLauncher` with `startActivityForResult`. Once the user clicks the photo, set the relevant information your `Photos` activity needs.

In `Photos` activity use `onActivityResult` method to do the necessary updates. Refer to the documentation for more details: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html.

Comment: That was what I needed. I set a boolen to true if a photo is taken and if It's true refresh refill the dataset.Thanks!